# ToolTip with image inside of it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hyperlink, tooltip

I currently have a hyperlink control as such:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="logoLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#"></asp:HyperLink>
```

I am setting the logo text of it as such within my grid:

```
    HyperLink logoLink = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("logoLink"); 
    logoLink.Text = lblsub + ".gif";
```

What I like to do is that when a user clicks on the hyperlink, I like the gif file to show within a tooltip.

what is the easiest way of doing this? The image is in the Image folder so the path would be as such:

```
    Images/ + lblsub + ".gif";
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jQuery/JavaScript` to achieve this.

There are different custom tooltips can be found online. 
I have came across this [Tooltip your images](http://ipicture-square.justmybit.com/) which is pretty cool.

Also have a look [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)